# How can I include a field from a parent object in my LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to add a field from an objects parent in my LINQ query but it's not working. Here are my classes:

```
public Problem()
    {
        this.Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual SubTopic SubTopic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question : AuditableTable
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionStatus QuestionStatus { get; set; }
}



 var questions = _questionsRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Include(q => q.Problem.SubTopicId)
            .Include(q => q.Answers)
            .ToList();
```

I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=A specified Include path is not valid. 
  The EntityType 'Models.Contexts.Problem' does not declare a navigation 
  property with the name 'SubTopicId'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `Include` the navigation property, not an ID:

```
.Include(x => x.Problem.SubTopic)
```

If I were you, I'd think about fetching what you *really need* from the database instead and returning a mapped object though, to lighten the load. And you have to be fairly sure you won't run into the N+1 problem somewhere... :)